# Is it possible to output audio from the speakers while a Bluetooth headset is connected?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio

In iOS, this is achieved by double-tapping the home button, swiping right twice, and selecting the speakers.

Can this be done in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by disconnecting the stereo audio (A2DP) profile from your headset. This still keeps your headset paired with the hands-free profile.

You can do this by opening Bluetooth settings, long-pressing your attached device and unchecking Stereo audio.